# It is possible in MongoDB do a query order by the near distance to a given GeoJSON point?

Tags: geojson, mongodb

I have in MongoDB a collection with GeoJSON Points that represent places of interest like this:

```
{
    "name" : "Malba",
    "type" : "Museum",
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            -58.474184, 
            -34.550208
        ]
    }

}
```

For example, I could have many points of type "Museum" with different location. It is possible to make a query in MongoDB to recover all this point order by the near distance of a given location?